# Why can't I use my datastore in my viewmodel Class?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, datastore

I have a datastore which I have declared using:

```
private val Context.recommendationDataStore : DataStore<RecConfigData> by dataStore(fileName = "Recommendations.json", serializer = RecommendationSerializer)
```

When I try to use it in some function in my Class :

```
class MainViewModel(private val context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    fun collectData(dataToCollect : JSONObject){
        recommendationDataStore.updateData {  }
    }
}
```

It does not recognise `recommendationDataStore`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You've created an extension on type `Context` and are trying to access it within an object of type `ViewModel`.

Given your code, you could just use the context you are passing in the contructor:

```
fun collectData(dataToCollect : JSONObject){
    context.recommendationDataStore.updateData {  }
}
```

Although you really [shouldn't hold a `Context` reference in a `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#best-practices).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I'll try remove this code from the viewmodel class, but at least it works now